# Forbidden 403 when trying to update modules

Tags: 7, updating

I just updated drupal core to 7.36. Next I needed to update some of my modules. I get through the auto download process, but when I proceed to the update I get a 403 error when trying to access authorize.php. Has anyone else had this occur, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Are you the super user on the site? Have you checked the file permissions for authorize.php?

Comment: Yep. I am the super user, and the permissions are rw-rw-r-- like that always have been.

Comment: In that case, head to line 242 in settings.php and change $update_free_access to TRUE and see if that works. Make sure you change it back when you are done!

Comment: That didn't help. This is really strange since I've never had trouble updating modules before.

Comment: Yeah that is strange. Did you do anything differently this time?

Comment: Nope. I just deleted all the files/folders except sites and .htaccess. Then copied over from the core update. I compared the .htaccess files and there appear to have been no changes between versions. I left mine in because it has custom code.

Comment: Have you tried copying the core files again? Maybe there was a problem with the transfer?

Comment: Have you run update.php?

Comment: I haven't recopied the core files, but I did run update.php. Everything else seems to run normal. It's just this one thing.